# Encryption (TripleDES) between Universal App and ASP.Net Web Service

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, win-universal-app, tripledes

I am totally lost. I build a Universal App (VB.net) which is consuming a web service on my (Azure Website Vb.net).

My Universal APP (UA) is sending userdata (Username an EmployeeNR) to a webservice and the Webservice is checking that data.

With TripleDES I encrypted the EmployeeNr and Username in the Universal and send it to the WebService. Now i am struggling how to decrypt the TripleDES on my WebService.

In the Universal App I work with Windows.Security.Cryptography which is not available on the Webservice site (asp.net).
I can only  use System.Security.Cryptography.

I can encrypt and decrypt on Windows App site. 
I also can encrpyt and decrypt on the Web Service site. 
But if I pass an encrypted String form Win App to Web Service. Decryption is not working.

Problem is: On both sides, I use the same STRING, same Key and TripleDES encryption, but the result is different.

MY Encryption side - Windows Universal APP

```
   Function myencrptor(ByVal Plaintext As String, ByVal mykey As String) As String
    Dim crypt As SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.TripleDesCbcPkcs7)

    Dim PlainTextbuffer As IBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(Plaintext, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8)
    Dim mykeybuffer As IBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(mykey, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8)

    Dim magickey As CryptographicKey = crypt.CreateSymmetricKey(mykeybuffer)

    Dim signed As IBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(magickey, PlainTextbuffer, Nothing)

    Dim verschlüsselt As String = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(signed)
    Return verschlüsselt
End Function
```

My Server Side

```
Partial Class regal_appsync_Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public NotInheritable Class Simple3Des
    Private xTripleDES As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
    Sub New(ByVal key As String)
        ' Initialize the crypto provider.
        xTripleDES.Key = TruncateHash(key, xTripleDES.KeySize \ 8)
        xTripleDES.IV = TruncateHash("", xTripleDES.BlockSize \ 8)
    End Sub
    Private Function TruncateHash(ByVal key As String, ByVal length As Integer) As Byte()
        Dim sha1 As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider

        ' Hash the key. 
        Dim keyBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)
        Dim hash() As Byte = sha1.ComputeHash(keyBytes)

        ' Truncate or pad the hash. 
        ReDim Preserve hash(length - 1)
        Return hash
    End Function

    Public Function EncryptData(ByVal plaintext As String) As String

        ' Convert the plaintext string to a byte array. 
        Dim plaintextBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext)

        ' Create the stream. 
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        ' Create the encoder to write to the stream. 
        Dim encStream As New CryptoStream(ms,
        xTripleDES.CreateEncryptor(),
        System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

        ' Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
        encStream.Write(plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length)
        encStream.FlushFinalBlock()

        ' Convert the encrypted stream to a printable string. 
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray)
    End Function

    Public Function DecryptData(ByVal encryptedtext As String) As String

        ' Convert the encrypted text string to a byte array. 
        Dim encryptedBytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedtext)

        ' Create the stream. 
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream

        ' Create the decoder to write to the stream. 
        Dim decStream As New CryptoStream(ms, xTripleDES.CreateDecryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

        ' Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
        decStream.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length)
        decStream.FlushFinalBlock()

        ' Convert the plaintext stream to a string. 
        Return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray)
    End Function
End Class
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Lbl1.Text = myEncoding(Txt1.Text)
End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Lbl1.Text = myDecoding(Lbl1.Text)
End Sub

Function myEncoding(ByVal plainText As String) As String

    Dim wrapper As New Simple3Des("012345678901234567891234")
    Dim cipherText As String = wrapper.EncryptData(plainText)

    Return cipherText
End Function

Function myDecoding(ByVal cipherText As String) As String

    ' DecryptData throws if the wrong password is used. 
    Dim wrapper As New Simple3Des("012345678901234567891234")
    Try
        Dim plainText As String = wrapper.DecryptData(cipherText)
        Return plainText

    Catch ex As System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
        Return "problem"
    End Try
End Function
```

End Class

looking forward to any helpful tips!
best wishes 
hendrik

Comment: Hi! ¿Did you found a solution?